# Detect Page Break jsPDF and jsPDF-AutoTable

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am generating a table using jsPDF and jsPDF-Autotable. and I want to add a line from my array after every page break.

I am using pageBreak: 'auto' to break a new page, which works great, and I get my headers on every page. After the header, I want to show a category header too, but I need to be able to detect when the page breaks. The category header is part of the array I'm creating to display all the information. Is this possible?

I've tried counting rows on my page but that is cumbersome and doesn't really seem to work anyway.

Here are some image examples.  This is the type of header I want to show up after the auto-generated header:

[image]

But what I'm getting at the top of my page is this... so I want to be able to detect when it's a new page and plop in my own header:

[image]

Thanks in advance.